# Usage of the word 'Abound'

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-meaning

The word Abound means to be present in large numbers or in great quantity. I was checking its usage and found it somewhat odd. Why don't they use 'be'(is, am, are, was, were) with abound. Like in these examples

1. They live in a region where oil abounds.
2. a city that abounds with art museums and private galleries.

What I think the sentences should be like :

1. They live in a region where oil is abound.
2. a city that is abound with art museums and private galleries.

These examples are from this link. [Examples](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abound#learn-more)

Isn't the word abound similar to excessive and abundant?

Comment: _Abound_ is a verb, and the definition which you quote includes the word _be_. _Excessive_ and _abundant_ are adjectives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike *excessive* and *abundant*, which are adjectives, [*abound*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abound) is an intransitive verb:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *intransitive verb*
>   **1** : to be present in large numbers or in great quantity : to be prevalent
>   // a business in which opportunities *abound*
>   // errors and inconsistencies *abound*
>   **2** : to be copiously supplied —used with *in* or *with*
>   // life *abounded* in mysteries
>   — Norman Mailer
>   // institutions *abound* with evidence of his success
>   — Johns Hopkins Magazine

It is an action, not a description.

---

Compare it to some other intransitive verbs as a cue for the grammar:

> ✔ They coughed loudly.
>   ✘ They **are** coughed loudly.
>
> ✔ She falls down and dies.
>   ✘ She **is** falls down and dies.
>
> ✔ They live in a region where oil abounds.
>   ✘ They live in a region where oil **is** abounds.
>
> ✔ [It is] a city that abounds with art museums and private galleries.
>   ✘ [It is] a city that **is** abounds with art galleries and private galleries.

---

Having said that, even intransitive verbs can take auxiliary verbs when other tenses and verb forms are used:

> ✔ They **are** ***coughing*** loudly.
>   ✔ She **is** ***falling*** down and ***dying***.

And so:

> ✔ They live in a region where oil **is** ***abounding***.
>   ✔ [It is] a city that **is** ***abounding*** with art museums and private galleries.

---

Although *abound* might sound similar to *excessive* and *abundant*, it is not actually an adjective like them. Therefore, different rules apply.

Comment: @JasonBassford..its pretty unique word. Seems like an adjective. What is the need of a verb in such a situation when we can easily use words like abundant and excessive?What is the importance of this word and in which context it is more useful?

Comment: I think the verb came first (Oxford Dictionaries says "Middle English (in the sense ‘overflow, be abundant’): from Old French abunder, from Latin abundare ‘overflow’, from ab- ‘from’ + undare ‘surge’ (from unda ‘a wave’)." _Abundant_ comes from the verb _to abound_. But the verb is now rather formal and would not be much used in everyday speech.